# How do I reset monitor to default resolution? (KDE)

Tags: kde, display-resolution, monitor

So! I want to preface this by noting that I am a virtually tech-illiterate n00b. Any answers - to be useful to me - will need to be really step-by-step.

My situation is this:

1. I'm running Kubuntu on a netbook.
2. I changed my screen resolution . . . and oops! Grey screen! Oh, well. Hard reset it is! But - nope - I log back in and am confronted with the same grey screen.
3. I think, "Ok - I can fix this!" and plug in an external monitor. Bam! Good to go. I change the setting back BUT! when I unplug the external monitor, my laptop reverts to the non-functional screen resolution, and I'm faced with a wall of grey.

Comment: See the `xrandr` command. You can use it to change the configuration of any connected screen. Also show actual & preferred mode for each.

Comment: Thank you elder geek! But can't you walk me through that a little?

Comment: Ok! Nm! Got it!!! Thank-you so much!!!!!